# UITableView Selected Row Position keep stay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController` and list of rows, i wired the prototype cell to a `NavigationController` & it's `rootViewController`, everything works perfectly, but once i select a row like row **no:10** and it takes to its master detail view and when i click to back button it takes me back to `UITableViewController` but this time `UITableViewController` scroll back to top position and it suppose to stay at row **no:10**, is their a way to keep my row position while i come back from detail view?.

Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1

```
class EventTableViewController: UITableViewController {

private let tableData:[Cell] = [
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 1",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 2",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 3",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 4",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 5",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 6",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 7",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 8",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 9",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    ),
    Cell(
        image: "burj_k",
        title: "Hola 10",
        place: "DFX",
        date: "SDSDs"
    )
]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
}
```

[image: Story board]

Comment: Show your `viewDidAppear` or similar methods in `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Do you call any method when go back? If Yes then show that as well.

Comment: I didnt use any method to go back, i just wired it with segue to tableview controller.

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa Could you please  
Show your `viewDidAppear` or similar lifecycle methods in `UITableViewController`?
Probably you are fetching the data in these lifecycle method that is why after reloading data it is going to initial position.

Comment: @Zaid Pathan please check my question, i just update the code.

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa Check properly that it is scroll back to top or its just clear the selection of cell on its appearance.

Comment: you should embed your tableviewcontroller in navigationcontroller. currently your structure in storyboard is not looking good.

Comment: if you create a segue to go back, a new Event Table View Controller is created, and you are not going back to the one you previously used.  You can check this by printing something in viewDidLoad, if it is called again, your are loading a new view.  Rather use unwind segues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a wrong structure,

Have this structure and you will have back button automatically by iOS, else you can add your own, no need to create unwind segue method in this case.

[image: New structure]

**Edit:**

If you want your own back button then you need to call on it's action,

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks i understand now, but i followed your story board structure and now last view not showing navigation bar or buttons, so can't go back.

Comment: It must be showing navigation bar, maybe you are hiding that in code, please search for "isHidden" property in your project, and you would probably find it.
Make sure your segue from TableViewController to ViewController is having **Kind** - **Show**

Comment: Glad that it's helped! This is concept of memory management, please learn more about it.

Comment: is their a way to create this things without navigation bar?

Comment: Yes, you could make TableViewController as initialViewController in storyboard, then call dismiss method on click of back button.

Comment: What have you tried? By the way you could do this to dismiss `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: in according to your storyboard you have to place tableViewController as root view controller of navigation controller. Current setup looks a bit odd.

You need to set UITableView's flag `tableView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true`.
docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614858-rememberslastfocusedindexpath)

If you don't reload data when you back to this controller (which 100% sure clears focus) it will work for your case. If you do reload data you'll need a some custom mechanism to save `indexPath` or object selected and restore this selection in `viewWillAppear` or other life-cycle methods.

Comment: in which place i have to do this?

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa when initialise a tableView. If you use storyboard you can check this flag in properties of a view in Interface Builder or in `viewDidLoad` of your controller.

Comment: But if he is just performing a segue and coming back using unwind then there should not be any change in table state, probably he is doing something else I guess.